# CHtmlView not refreshing

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, mfc

I have a `CHtmlView` which does not always refresh itself - after being resized or even sometimes on load. Hovering the mouse over elements make them re-appear - sometimes a new resize does the trick (sometimes not).
I am using Visual Studio 2010.

This looks like what's happening here:
[IE9 web control not redrawing itself in CHtmlView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344413/ie9-web-control-not-redrawing-itself-in-chtmlview)

And there:
[MFC chtmlview Windows 7 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194990/mfc-chtmlview-windows-7-issue)

But nowhere (knowingly) do I trap the `WM_PAINT` message... and I use a (relatively) recent version of Visual Studio.

Any help welcome!
Thanks,
Jerome

Comment: I found a similar problem, but it is quite old. Anyway, did you try [this fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/220021)?

Comment: Thanks, yes I did and to no avail. This was a bug in older versions of MFC. Apprently it is fixed but this is something different. Thanks though!

Comment: you should post some code so we can see what's going on

Comment: Hey Robson - there is actually quite a lot of it. The main window is a dialog. It has a control which is actually a CFormView (which lets me simulate the view of an iPhone and an iPad). The CHtmlView is a control n the CFormView...

Answer (score 0):

A year and 1/2 on... I found the solution. The container of my view was a derived `CFormView`. But the `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP` macro was done on `CWnd` not on `CFormView`...

Comment: i sometimes have the same rendering issues, but your answer here is not my problem so I am still at a loss.

Comment: I found this discussion https://microsoft.public.vc.mfc.narkive.com/0rnPC327/chtmlview-refresh-problem and an archived version of the MS KB article referred to: https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/220/Q220021/ so I will try that.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle You gave me great hope because this bug still intermittently happens but it still does in spite of the fix... I am thinking of using IWebView2 (which uses chromium) but I do not know what to do about another of my classes which derives from CHtmlEditCtrl... MFC does not get much love these days...

Comment: At the moment mine is rendring OK. I am not even attemping to use `IWebView2` because it is lacking too much features. Once it can become a like for like transfer to that environment with no loss of features I will do it.